# Using select2, how can I get multiple data by PHP using CodeIgniter?

Tags: php

Here is my view page. How can I add multiple data from here?

```
  <select multiple  id="e19">
      <option value="January">January</option>
      <option value="February">February</option>
      <option value="March">March</option>
      <option value="April">April</option>
      <option value="May">May</option>
      <option value="June">June</option>
      <option value="July">July</option>
      <option value="August">August</option>
      <option value="September">September</option>
      <option value="October">October</option>
      <option value="November">November</option>
      <option value="December">December</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense. Can you please provide more details about your question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't mantion the name of `select` tag which is mandatory.

Ok. Let the name of `select` tag is 'month'
then your code will look like that

`<select multiple  id="e19" name="month[]">`

Now in your controller you will get an array with selected item.

Let you have select 3 Item which are `January`, `April` and `December`

Now you print the `$_POST['month']`

Here I give an example in CI

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($this->input->post('month'))
echo '</pre>';
```

Then your output will be look like that

```
array(
      '0' => 'January'
      '1' => 'April'
      '2' => 'December'
)
```

Now you can do with this array whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you write:

```
<form method="post">
<select multiple name="e19[]">
```

then $_POST['e19'] is an array that contains all the values selected by the user.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a `name` attribute to the `select` element, and you will get the array selected options in PHP.

```
 <select multiple name="select[]" id="e19">
   <option value="January">January</option>
   <option value="February">February</option>
   <option value="March">March</option>
   <option value="April">April</option>
   <option value="May">May</option>
   <option value="June">June</option>
   <option value="July">July</option>
   <option value="August">August</option>
   <option value="September">September</option>
   <option value="October">October</option>
   <option value="November">November</option>
   <option value="December">December</option>
</select>
```

Access it from CodeIgniter:

```
$options = $this->input->post('select');
foreach($options as $option){
    echo $option;
}
```

Comment: @InspireShahin yap i missed that, glad it's working, don't forget to mark it as the accepted answer